# String conversion to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In this screenshot data (string datatype) and df2 (pandas dataframe) store the same data - a timestamp and a value.

[image]

How do I get data in a similar dataframe so I can append the values to df2 so I have all the data records and all the df2 records in one dataframe and matching the current format of df2 ?

I can post what I've tried so far, but all I get is errors :(

Comment: Looks like you need to convert data to a dict...use the `json` module.

Answer (score 1):

```
import ast 
import pandas as pd
data = "[[1212.1221, -10.5],[2232.55, -19.44],[32432.87655, -445.88]]"
df = pd.DataFrame(ast.literal_eval(data),
                 columns=['index', 'data'])
```

Comment: That almost works, but the first column (index) should be an epoch time converted to a proper datetime.  Is there a way I can do that in the DataFrame definition - basically to say that it's a datetime and then a float value ?

Comment: Do you mean this (in the answer code): 
df = pd.DataFrame(ast.literal_eval(data),dtype=np.float32,
                     columns=['index', 'data'], index=pd.date_range('20190101',periods=3,freq='T'))

Comment: I get the error : ValueError: Shape of passed values is (2, 2000), indices imply (2, 3)

I think this is because I don't have 3 sets of values, I have X (as in the number will change) and if I'm reading your code properly you think it's a date but it's an epoch time (down to the millisecond), which must be preserved.

I know it's my own lack of knowledge in Python, I know I'm trying to shortcut things and "just get it done", and I'm happy to adapt code to my situation ... I just need to know what the code really does.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your string data is a correctly formatted json (which from my knowledge looks exactly like Python dictionaries but is strict about double quotes over single quotes). Try:

```
import json
dict = json.loads(data)
```

This will convert your string into dict type from which you can easily create and manipulate DataFrames.

EDIT:

If any of your strings have single quotes, you can remedy this using str.replace("'", "\"") to convert them to double quotes. This will only cause problems if for whatever reason your data has incorrectly paired quotes.

Comment: I'm only using double quotes, but this is my problem:

>>> print (data[:100])
{"data":[[1546992043.3410804, -10.070938800134865], [1546992128.6818917, -10.24111650646369], [15469
>>> dict = json.loads(data)
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 422, in __init__
    raise ValueError('DataFrame constructor not properly called!')
ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!
>>>

Comment: Hi @cmcau, be sure to call the DataFrame constructor on the dict object, not the string again: pd.DataFrame(dict), not pd.DataFrame(data). The data variable is still holding a string. Your dict object can be directly converted into a DataFrame.